# Unicode-math: subscripts work with Bitstream Vera Sans, but not with DejaVu Sans

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode-math

I'm trying to typeset some slides with text in either *Bitstream Vera Sans* or *DejaVu Sans* and maths in *Fira Math* using *LuaLaTeX* and `unicode-math`.  When using *Bitstream Vera Sans*, everything works fine (except for the many glyphs missing in *Fira Math*):

[image: Bitstream Vera Sans]

When using *DejaVu Sans*, on the other hand, subscripts don't:

[image: DejaVu Sans]

What could be the cause of the difference?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
% \setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin}]{Bitstream Vera Sans}
% \setmathfont[range=it/{latin,Latin}]{Bitstream Vera Sans Oblique}
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin}]{DejaVu Sans}
\setmathfont[range=it/{latin,Latin}]{DejaVu Sans Oblique}
\begin{document}
\[ a_i \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: looks okay here. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: TeXLive 2020, as packaged by Norbert for Debian Unstable.

Comment: I can’t reproduce the bug on my own box. What version of `DejaVuSans.ttf` does `otfinfo -i` report?

Comment: Version 2.37 (for both the regular and oblique variants).  As an additional element, the issue doesn't occur if I remove the `up` substitution, even though the `up` shapes are not used in the sample document.